# tbb::concurrent_hash_map - how to return if key-entry is blocked by other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, hashmap, tbb

i'm writing a program, where are multiple threads add entries to an (tbb::concurrent_hash_map) hash map and at the same time other threads travers this map and manipulate the entries on the hash map. At each time one thread manipulat and work with one entry and blocks this entry with an accessor (so that there won't be a conflict and no other thread can access this entry). After manipulating the data, the thread insert the data and release the accessor.

My problem now is that a thread how access a blocked entry is waiting till the accessor of this entry is released even if other entries on the hash map are not blocked. The goal i want to achieve is, that threads skipping blocked entries and go the the next nonblocked entry or return to my function. Is there a good solution for it?

The following code snippet as short single thread example:

```
...
typdef tbb::concurrent_hash_map<int,unsigned int> typ_hash_map;
typ_hash_map hash_map;
typ_hash_map::accessor acc;
typ_hash_map::accessor acc2;
//hash_map filled with 4 entries...

//block second entry in hash map
typ_hash_map::iterator k = hash_map.begin();
k++;
config.hash_map.insert(acc,k->first);

//travers all entries in hash_map
for(typ_hash_map::iterator j = hash_map.begin();j!=hash_map.end(); j++){
           hash_map.find(acc2,j->first); // my problem: return if entry is blocked - at the moment its waiting till acc is released
            /*
            Do something with acc2->second if entry is not blocked, 
            else continue;
            */
          }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that traversing `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` is not thread-safe? If your code is serial, there is nothing to protect then: so, you don't need to hold an accessor.

In any case, locking an element for a long time is a bad idea because it hurts scalability and leads to deadlocks like yours, it should be released immediately when the update is done or data is read.

General rule for concurrent_hash_map is: do not run any hash table operation on other acccessors while holding the first one.

So, just release the accessor `acc` as soon you done with it: `acc.release()`